# Bootstrap 'scrollTo' functionality built in?

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, scrolltop

I've noticed that, whenever I have a link that has `href="#"` my browser scrolls (animates) to the top of the page... similar to using the scrollTo jQuery plugin.

Is there a way to disable this? or even better, is there a way to offset it in the same way that I can with jQuery? e.g:

```
scrollTop: $(".feed-quotes").offset().top -30
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the href ?

Comment: *is there a way to disable this* - stop using `<a href="#"` - **it's semantically incorrect** - use a `<button type="button"` - an `<a>` is meant to *link* somewhere, if you're using it as an "action" then you're using it incorrectly.

Comment: Or just `return false` from your click event handler

Comment: Also you can set the href to "!#" and it also works